# How can I apply style to a div based on condition?

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller

I have a div, i want to show/hide it when condition.

I use this.

```
<div th:style="${@Model.SelectionList.Any()} ? 'display:block' : 'display:none'">
```

But don't hide div.

Comment: I don't think that it's css problem. Has to be your js

Comment: css, can i use condition in style css?

Comment: From your code sample ive understood that the condition is written in JS (or is dependant on js variable). Your framework takes care for processing it further (right?). While there are some ways to mimic conditions in CSS i dont think it'll help in your case. Try to debug the js code, check if your `Model. SelectiionList.Any()` contains the right value.

Comment: What is the condition upon which you wish to show the element? While CSS doesn't have `if` conditions as such, there are some means of applying if-like behaviour, but we can't help if we don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply use

**For C#**

```
<div style='@String.Format("{0}", (Model.SelectionList.Any() ? "display:block" : "display:none"))'>
```

**For VB**

```
<div style='@String.Format("{0}", If(Model.SelectionList.Any(), "display:block", "display:none"))'>
```

**For ThymeLeaf**

extend the curly braces

```
<div th:style="${@Model.SelectionList.Any() ? 'display:block' : 'display:none'}">
```

Comment: Well, it would be worthy to say that one actually cant use conditionals in css. And to mention that one should just not render porition of the page instead of just visually hiding it.

Comment: @entio The goal here is to hide the target element from the page using conditional block which is the fastest way possible. If one cant use conditionals for style like you stated then the option for code block inside style attributes would not be created for it at first. And also **"rendering portion of the page"** Vs **"just visually hiding it"** which do you think would load faster?

Comment: Yes, that was precisely what i meant. Html sent over server with no div will render faster than html with the div, simply, because it's smaller.

In general, the question misses context (ThymeLeaf [check your spelling, btw.]). If you're using it the way proposed it does not have anything to do with html (tag), only remotely related to css (tag) and the relation to MVC (tag) doesn't really as anything.